# Can I do an Array.join() with an HTML tag in React, using JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I would like to use the join() method on a Javascript array, but I would like to join() with an HTML tag.

I want to do something like:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <p>
           {this.props.the_form['candidate_ids'].map((val,idx) => {
               return this.getCandidateName(val);
           }).join('<br/>')}
        </p>
    }
}
```

It's escaping the tag and not rendering a new line.

I'm using React, Webpack, and Babel.

Comment: Escaping is performed by your framework, not JS itself. The line you provided generates a correct HTML. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details about the framework you use.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't considered that it could be Babel or React.

Comment: This is really not the proper way to do this in react, you're already mapping the items, you should return simple html, not a string representation of html. See my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to add this, since `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and joining a long string isn't really the react way to do it, and a bit misleading. Plus, you're missing the `key` on your mapped items

```
//import Fragment
import { Fragment, Component } from "react"

class Page extends Component {
  const ids = this.props.the_form['candidate_ids'];
  render() {
    <p>
      {ids.map((val, idx) => {
        const name = this.getCandidateName(val);
        return (
          <Fragment key={`${name}${idx}`}>
            {name}
            {idx < ids.length - 1 && <br />}
          </Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </p>
  }
}
```

(updated to remove the trailing `<br/>`).

And here's a possible alternate version with no `<br/>`'s:

```
class Page extends Component {
  const ids = this.props.the_form['candidate_ids'];
  render() {
    <p>
      {ids.map((val, idx) => {
        const name = this.getCandidateName(val);
        return (
          <span key={`${name}${idx}`} style={{display: 'block'}}>
            {name}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </p>
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is much cleaner than what I've been doing.  It is leaving a trailing break tag, which is why I was using join and map in the first place.

Comment: I'll probably add a ternary operator to deal with that, but it would be nice to have something cleaner.

Comment: Ah that's a snazzy solution to use a block.  I had been using a comma, and wanted to make the list easier to read at a glance.  I appreciate the use of Fragment and the bit of React I've learned now.  Cheers!

Comment: This is nice! Very slight optimization could be swap `{name}{idx < ids.length - 1 && <br />}` for `{!!idx && <br/>}{name}`. The !! casts the idx number to a boolean, otherwize jsx will print it.

Comment: This also works when you replace `<Fragment>` with `<>` if you don't need a key.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. Assuming there is no framework at play here, the only thing I'd point out that you need to use `innerHTML` function

```js
var mArray =[ 'line 1', 'line 2'];

document.body.innerHTML = mArray.map((val,idx) => { return `sometext: <strong>${val}</strong>`; }).join('<br/>')
```

---

## update:

since you're using react, you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const html = this.props.the_form['candidate_ids'].map((val,idx) => {
               return this.getCandidateName(val);
           }).join('<br/>')
        return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:html}}></p>
    }
}
```

But since you're using JSX, you shouldn't need to use strings and dangerouslySetInnerHTML. You can also just use jsx to compose your dom:

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {the_form} = this.props;
        const dom = the_form['candidate_ids'].map((val,idx) => {
           return (
             <>
               {this.getCandidateName(val)}
               {idx+1 < the_form['candidate_ids'].length ? </br> : null}
             </>
           );
        }))
        return (<p>{dom}</p>);
    }
}
```

docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I'm using React and Babel.

Comment: I'm using JSX templates.  I've edited my question to provide a better example.

Comment: Actually, this threw an error: `Uncaught Error: props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML must be in the form `{__html: ...}`

Comment: This is really bad form for react